# Xcode 5/iOS SDK 7.0: UIImageView not displayed correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview, xcode5

I moved my project to Xcode 5 and then it changed some of my views locations on the screen.

In particular a couple of UIImageViews were given way out of bounds coordinates (something like x=-3000). I corrected their coordinates and since then these views are only displayed on iPhone 5. On iPhone 3-4 they are not displayed at all.

Before moving to Xcode 5 it worked perfectly on all devices.
Has anyone encountered this issue and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling for iOS7? Maybe you did some conversion to autolayout which did some wrong adjustments.